# How get elements from XML and send it to array? C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I have this XML (a small sample):

```
<response list='true'>
    <count>12</count>
    <post>
        <id>307</id>
        <from_id>123</from_id>
        <to_id>123</to_id>
        <date>123892128</date>
        <post_type>post</post_type>
        <text>Smth TExt</text>
        <attachments list='true'>
            <attachment>
                <type>photo</type>
                <photo>
                    <pid>123</pid>
                    <aid>-7</aid>
                    <owner_id>123</owner_id>
                    <src>http://url1.jpg</src>
                    <src_big>http://url2.jpg</src_big>
                    <src_small>http://url3.jpg</src_small>
                    <src_xbig>http://url4.jpg</src_xbig>
                    <src_xxbig>http://url5.jpg</src_xxbig>
                    <src_xxxbig>http://url6.jpg</src_xxxbig>
                    <width>990</width>
                    <height>1188</height>
                    <text/>
                    <created>135</created>
                    <access_key>67</access_key>
                </photo>
            </attachment>
            <attachment>...</attachment>
            <attachment>...</attachment>
        </attachments>
        <comments><count>0</count></comments>
        <likes><count>2</count></likes>
        <reposts><count>0</count></reposts>
    </post>
</response>
```

I need to get values from each post and send it to arrays like these:

```
 int[] int_from_id;
 int[] comments_count;
 int[] owner_id;
 string[,] srcofxxxbig; //where [post, № of att]
```

How can I do this? I could get count from this -  12, but I can't get value of elements in each post. It's Windows 8.1 App. Visual Studio 2013.
I have tried (2 Paul Sasik):

```
  private void name(){
       XDocument parsedoc = XDocument.Parse(herelinktoxmldoc);
       foreach (XElement i in parsedoc.Root.Elements())
      {
         if (w==0)
         {
             count =  Convert.ToInt32(i.Value);
         }
         w++;
     }
     count += 0;
     string[] post_from_id = new String[count];
     string[] post_to_id = new String[count];
     string[] post_date = new String[count];
     string[] post_text = new String[count];
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {

         post_from_id[i] = ParsingXmlwoReq(wallxmlstring, "from_id");
         post_to_id[i] = ParsingXmlwoReq(wallxmlstring, "to_id");
         post_date[i] = ParsingXmlwoReq(wallxmlstring, "date");
         post_text[i] = ParsingXmlwoReq(wallxmlstring, "text");

     }
     }
     }
    private string ParsingXmlwoReq(string request, string whatget)
    {
        XDocument parsedoc = XDocument.Parse(request);
        string forreturn = "Null";
        var get = (from uri in parsedoc.Descendants(whatget) select uri.Value);
        foreach (var element in get)
        {
            forreturn = System.Convert.ToString(element);

        }
        return forreturn;
     }
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried so far? The question right now asks: Please do my work for me. That kind of question is not welcome on SO.

Comment: I think it would be bad form to post this as an answer, but try HtmlAgilityPack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ It is a library designed for parsing and traversing XML and HTML. I have not done the research to ensure that it will work in a Windows 8.1 App, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: The agility pack is a nice tool +1 but the OP doesn't need much to accomplish what I think the code is trying to accomplish. There are simple XML APIs built into .NET already and can be used quite simply with XPath expressions. IMHO an external library in this case is overkill.

Comment: @PaulSasik - I agree, completely. I added that comment before he added code to the OP. Had I seen it earlier, I wouldn't have commented with that. It's why I thought it bad form to post as an answer ;)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: Lol. Awesome! +1 I was actually going to commend you for not posting an answer. :-) That was before I got lost in the OP and my answer and interpretation... But now I feel silly. I may have just written a hundred lines of code that feeds a budding help vampire with a good chance that it will get copy/pasted right into production code. I should -1 myself. :-)

Comment: Hahaha :) It was a good solution - I'm not downvoting it :P

Comment: I just realized that the OP may be approaching the issue with a very procedural/imperative manner, perhaps in the style of a C program. (OP, do you have a background in C, Fortran, RPG, COBOL etc.?) That said, C# and any OOP language requires a different approach. C# is OOP but isn't exactly declarative on its own. But with judicious research and use into existing APIs and arranging ones own code according to SoC, (also understanding that you or other humans may sooner or later need to read this code...) C# can look quite elegant (and any language really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the XML in the most complex way possible. There's no need. There are much simpler methods built in. (See the code below.)

For the example code I simplified and hard coded the XML into a local string and there is no error checking! The example is basic but if you understand the `XmlDocument.SelectNodes` method and its XPath expression argument (sample `/response/post` will work with your response XML already) then you can reuse it at any level you of the document you choose. Whatever you do, first think to yourself: "Has someone already done this kind of operation before and is there possibly an API for it?" The answers 99.9% of the time are **Yes** and **Yes**.

I would also recommend creating a data class to match your XML doc and a `List<YourDataClass>` to contain the instances. From your code sample it looks like you're trying to add the data items into separate array. This is unnecessarily complex and dangerous since the only data linking one array's datum to the next is the index! See a sample class structure in the original example, added at the bottom. (I retained the XML value samples with the properties for easy mapping to your XML doc.)

Here is a handy tutorial as a base to get started as well as exploring other ways to access the XML doc: http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/

```
private void ReadDoc()
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xmlString); // your test XML (hard coded below)

    XmlNodeList postList = xml.SelectNodes("/response/post");
    Console.WriteLine(postList.Count);
    foreach (XmlNode post in postList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(post["from_id"]);
        Console.WriteLine(post["to_id"]);
        Console.WriteLine(post["date"]);
        Console.WriteLine(post["text"]);
    }
}

string xmlString = @"
<response list='true'>
    <count>12</count>
    <post>
        <id>307</id>
        <from_id>123</from_id>
        <to_id>123</to_id>
        <date>123892128</date>
        <post_type>post</post_type>
        <text>Smth TExt</text>
        <attachments list='true'>
            <attachment>
                <type>photo</type>
                <photo>
                    <pid>123</pid>
                    <aid>-7</aid>
                    <owner_id>123</owner_id>
                    <src>http://url1.jpg</src>
                    <src_big>http://url2.jpg</src_big>
                    <src_small>http://url3.jpg</src_small>
                    <src_xbig>http://url4.jpg</src_xbig>
                    <src_xxbig>http://url5.jpg</src_xxbig>
                    <src_xxxbig>http://url6.jpg</src_xxxbig>
                    <width>990</width>
                    <height>1188</height>
                    <text/>
                    <created>135</created>
                    <access_key>67</access_key>
                </photo>
            </attachment>
            <attachment>...</attachment>
            <attachment>...</attachment>
        </attachments>
        <comments><count>0</count></comments>
        <likes><count>2</count></likes>
        <reposts><count>0</count></reposts>
    </post>
</response>
";
```

Sample data class structure:

```
public class Post // <post>
{
    int PostId { get; set; } // <id>307</id>
    int FromId { get; set; } // <<from_id>123</from_id>
    int ToId { get; set; } // <<to_id>123</to_id>
    DateTime PostDate { get; set; } // <<date>123892128</date>
    string PostType { get; set; } // <<post_type>post</post_type>
    string Text { get; set; } // <<text>Smth TExt</text>
    List<PostAttachment> Attachments { get; set; } // <attachments list="true">
}

public class PostAttachment // <attachment>
{
  string AttachmentType { get; set; } // <type>photo</type>
  List<Photo> AttachedPhotos { get; set; } // <photo>
}

public class Photo 
{
    int PhotoId { get; set; } // <pid>123</pid>
    int AId { get; set; } // <aid>-7</aid>
    int OwnerId { get; set; } // <owner_id>123</owner_id>
    string Source { get; set; } // <src>http://url1.jpg</src>
    string Source1Small { get; set; } // <src_small>http://url3.jpg</src_small>
    string Source2Big { get; set; } // <src_big>http://url2.jpg</src_big>
    string Source3XBig { get; set; } // <src_xbig>http://url4.jpg</src_xbig>
    string Source4XXBig { get; set; } // <src_xxbig>http://url5.jpg</src_xxbig>
    string Source5XXXBig { get; set; } // <src_xxxbig>http://url6.jpg</src_xxxbig>
    int Width { get; set; } // <width>990</width>
    int Height { get; set; } // <height>1188</height>
    string Text { get; set; } // <text/>
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } // <created>135</created>
    int AccessKey { get; set; } // <access_key>67</access_key>
}
```